# What does 壓軸 mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a drama I am watching, a guy is being called out for being dressed like Michael Jackson at a school reunion. He mentions that his invitation card said it would be a 90s celebrity cosplay party. The host then says this, in passing:

> 抱歉，我想說他壓軸

I have found 壓軸 in dictionaries and I have also encountered it before in novels, where it has made sense to me. Here it trips me up though. Dictionary entry (in English):

> 1 grand finale (last and best item in a theatrical programme), ≪pièce de résistance≫
> 2 {in former times} the next to last act in a theatrical programme

Comment: Seems to be an incomplete sentence.

Comment: She doesn't say anything else, and she is not cut off by another speaker.  

Speaker #1: 大芳給我的邀請函上面有著裝要求啊. 90年代巨星風啊.  
Speaker #2: 抱歉，我想說他壓軸  

The conversation then moves on to another topic.

Comment: It is important to know what Speaker #2 said that drew this response from Speaker #1; who was "he", and what type of dress he wore, which might have been excel from the 着装要求.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ask my smart and beautiful friend, 晓云。She immediately said:

抱歉，我想說他壓軸。
Sorry, I wanted to say, he was the greatest!

on a notion of "save the best till last"

The plot [thickens](https://hanyu.baidu.com/zici/s?wd=%E5%8E%8B%E8%BD%B4&query=%E5%8E%8B%E8%BD%B4%E7%9A%84%E6%84%8F%E6%80%9D&srcid=28236&from=kg0):

Contrary to popular belief 压轴 actually doesn't mean: "the finale, the last and, presumably best, act"

> 压轴”原本是戏曲名词，指一场折子戏演出的倒数第二个剧目。在现代社会中有很多应用，比如“压轴戏”，但压轴也是人们知识的一个盲区。“压轴”本意是指倒数第二个节目，而不是人们常说的倒数第一个，倒数第一个节目称“压台”。

“压轴”本意是指倒数第二个节目, 而不是人们常说的倒数第一个

倒数第一个节目称“压台”。
counting backwards, the first item is called “压台”。

Comment: I learnt this word when I was reading Taipei People by Pai-Hsien Young and it seems to mean both. According to the Cross-Straits dictionary as well, like the KEY dictionary I cited above, it seems to first have meant the second but last performance, but in modern times *also* means highlight / last performance in general. "泛指最精彩、令人注目的結尾或最後出現的事件。" You're answer makes sense to the scene in general so I will mark it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

No matter whether the 压轴戏 is the second to the last play or the last play,
压轴戏 is usually played by the most famous/important actors in the group (戏班挂头牌的主要演员), so the sentence goes as "抱歉，我想說他**是/挂头牌**" - "Sorry, I wanted to say he is the best (number one).